# Gnome shell text getting messed up

Tags: gnome

image showing messed up ubuntu gnome shell text

[image: image showing messed up ubuntu gnome shell text]

im facing this problem since recent upgrade, all texts related to gnome top panel,overlay and gnome shell get messed up, only few letters are displayed.
just au[blank spaces for missing letters]s is being displayed for audacious in gnome search results. Whatever i type in the search bar get messy too.

i dont face this everytime i use ubuntu. the last time i faced the problem i ran software update and the problem got solved. It worked fine for a few days but i got the problem back.

text in applications are fine.

Comment: What recent upgrade? Are you still using 15.04? If so, your question is off topic here since we don't deal with versions that are no longer supported. If you mean that you upgraded _from_ 15.04, please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: sorry for the mistake,im using 15.10 and not 15.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Have you tried a `fc-cache --force --system --verbose`?

Comment: @Fabby tried using the command, doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

I'm suffering the same issue and I'm debugging it. While I haven't found the root cause, I've found that the issue is in cogl's glyph cache for Pango. You can use a debugger to clear this cache. I'm going to detail the steps here, but I should warn you that this is a bit of an expert option.

Preparation you need to do once to make the workaround work:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb gnome-shell-dbg libclutter-1.0-dbg libcogl-pango20-dbg
```

Then whenever you run into the issue, clear the font cache by running the following command line:

```
sudo gdb -p `pgrep -u $USER -x gnome-shell` <<<"print /r _cogl_pango_renderer_clear_glyph_cache((CoglPangoRenderer*)(_cogl_pango_font_map_get_priv(clutter_context_get_pango_fontmap())->renderer))"
```

This works splendidly for me, but I should warn you that if this command goes awry for any reason, it may hang your system. If that happens, a reboot is the only thing that fixes it.

I'm going to investigate further what, exactly, is wrong with the glyph cache, and open a bug report upstream.

Hope that helps!

Explanation of the command line: the part between backticks finds the process id for `gnome-shell`. That is used to attach the debugger `gdb` to the process; you need to be root (`sudo`) to do that. The part between `<<<"` and `"` is the function call for clearing the glyph cache.

Comment: It didn't do the trick for me, see the output https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/ee7de70576aa5e58d5393eaa6fb5d428. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. To fix the issue, restart the gnome shell. Press `Alt`+`F2`, enter `r`, and press `return/enter`. I do not think this is a permanent solution, but it will get your text back.