# Ubuntu text is randomly corrupted

Tags: gnome, unity, 22.04, text

From time to time all the text in my Ubuntu Desktop menus gets corrupted.  The text inside the applications is OK, but it looks like all, or most, of the text related to Gnome is corrupted.

This includes the menus which are displayed when clicking on the network/volume/power off icons, the menus in the rest of the icons in the bar, the tooltips in the left bar, the text in the window that is displayed when clicking on the clock, and also the text in the application displayed when clicking the Windows key.

A couple of screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas about how to fix this?  There is [a similar issue in an old Ubuntu version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756275/gnome-shell-text-getting-messed-up).

Comment: 1) What's your Ubuntu version?  
2) I had this once, it was many years ago, still with Gnome 2. I had exactly the "ff" letters here and there, wondering why "ff" works?! 
 I recall I reinstalled a lot if packages, and then it started working. Perhaps it was the whole deps tree of Gnome.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This happens to me too, but only if I've had Minecraft running for a long time, not sure what the correlation is there. I found that when running X-ORG I could press ALT + F2 and type `r` the press Enter to restart Gnome, this would resolve the problem. In Wayland this isn't possible. It's happened for me since 20.04 at least.

Comment: My system is using Wayland, when I try the ALT + F2, r trick I get this message:  "Restart is not available on Wayland"

Comment: I have noticed that this problem only happens when I have [DIGIstorage application](https://digistorage.es/dl/apps/linux64) running in the background.  Maybe there is something wrong in this app?  Or maybe it is using something not well supported by Ubuntu 22.04 ?

Comment: This problem happens both on Wayland and Xorg.

Comment: This issue also happens when running [Koofr application](https://koofr.eu) which shares the same codebase with DIGIStorage.